# why pass viewController as variable?

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

First of all I have to say I am really new to swift and Objective C.I am learning them by myself.

I have a question for this code

I have a delegate in my SettingViewController called "settingsViewControllerFinished" and it pass the whole controller as a variable.
the code like this:

in my SettingViewController.swift

```
protocol SettingViewControllerDelegate: class {
func settingsViewControllerFinished(settingsViewController: SettingsViewController)
```

}

```
@IBAction func close(sender: AnyObject) {
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
self.delegate?.settingsViewControllerFinished(self)
```

}

I am confused.What did you mean if you pass the whole controller as a variable?(maybe the question is silly for you)

---

in my viewController:

```
func settingsViewControllerFinished(settingsViewController: SettingsViewController)
{
    self.brushWidth = settingsViewController.brush
    self.opacity = settingsViewController.opacity
    self.red = settingsViewController.red
    self.green = settingsViewController.green
    self.blue = settingsViewController.blue
}
```

I guess the reason is:I pass everything in SettingViewController to ViewController so that I could use the variables in SettingViewController.

Am I rihgt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you are correct, **yes**: passing the `SettingViewController` back to its delegate enables the original caller to not have to keep a reference to the created and shown `SettingViewController` since the delegate method sends the relevant information along already.

**But there is more**: In some cases of delegates this style is useful for something different. Imagine a click handler consisting of a function `func somethingGotClicked(sender:YourSenderType)`. If your class creates multiple instances of `YourSenderType` and shows them at the same time registering itself as their delegate there would be no way to know *which* one got clicked if there was no `sender` parameter. In some `func somethingGotClicked()` you would not know which one got clicked. That capability is often needed when showing multiple `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` is one single view with one single instances set as their delegate.